# How i can put the username folder path in puppet?

Tags: ruby, windows, puppet

I want to copy a file into the user folder (ex: C:/Users/**User**/ in a puppet module but not all the users are named as **User** how i can told to puppet to use the username as a part of the path, something like

```
command => 'C:\\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "copy pathfrom C:/Users/HereUsername/file",
```

Thanks

Comment: String interpolation? `"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe /c \"copy pathfrom C:/Users/#{user_name}/file\"`

Comment: If I double quote " all the command I'm getting an error, if i put the  \#{user_name} with single quote it didn't find the path, anywhere any of two worked as expected. I forgot on the first coment to quote correctly. It looks like  '(single quote)C:\\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c "(double quote)copy C:\temporal\file C:\Users\HereUsername\file"' (single & double quote),